# Checking whether an archive is password-protected in Sevenzipsharp (C#)

Tags: c#, passwords, sevenzipsharp

I'm writing an window form similar to 7-Zip, my problem is in the extraction part, I don't know how to check if the archive I want to extract is password protected or not.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the solution: just check the extractor before extracting the archive:

```
if (fileExtractor.Check())
{
   fileExtractor.BeginExtractArchive(destination_dir);
}
```

Doing it this way the `fileExtractor.Check()` will be `false`, if the archive requires a password, and you're not providing the password for it or the password is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the archive type.  The [ZIP specification](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEUQFjAA&url=http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT&ei=SImxTvGGLoaNsQKt4JDKAQ&usg=AFQjCNG3PQ4djfATtOeHgUrCcLYE3id5PA&sig2=pA8ic9kaTZaNb12076S1RQ) describes how it's done for ZIP, although it's not very robust apparently.